# Content collapsing inside div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with callpsing content in html. I don't know how to explain this clearly so I will show you what I mean.

For instance I have two divs:

```
<div class="row">

 <div class="col-md-6">
  (Some image)
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-6">
  (some image)
  <p>content</p>
 </div>

</div>
```

I want images to be on the same height regardless of amount of content but they look like this:

```
------     ------
(image)
content    (image)
content    content
------     -------
```

Somehow the position of the image depends on the amount of content.
I don't see any padding or margin in second div

Answer (score 0):

Use the float property so the images stay at the top lile you want it or use verticle-align to make it positioned where u want it.

Comment: content is still collapsing.